# Prolog - Avoid Infinite Loop

Tags: prolog, infinite-loop

I am currently studying logic programming, and learn `Prolog` for that case.

We can have a `Knowledge Base`, which can lead us to some `results`, whereas `Prolog` will get in infinite loop, due to the way it expands the predicates.

Let assume we have the following `logic program`

```
p(X):- p(X).
p(X):- q(X).
q(X).
```

The query `p(john)` will get to an infinite loop because `Prolog` expands by default the first predicate that is unified. However, we can conclude that `p(john)` is true if we start expanding the second predicate.

So why doesn't `Prolog` expand all the matching predicates (implemented like threads/processes model with time slices), in order to conclude something if the `KB` can conclude something ?

In our case for example, two processes can be created, one expanded with p(X) and the other one with q(X). So when we later expand q(X), our program will conclude `q(john)`.

Comment: The rule, `p(X) :- p(X).` is an obvious infinite recursion and it doesn't add any logical value. It should be removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Prolog's search algorithm for matching predicates is [depth-first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). So, in your example, once matching the first rule, it will match again the first rule, and will never explore the others.

This would not happen if the algorithm is [breadth-first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [iterative-deepening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search).

Usually is up to you to reorder the KB such that these situations never happen.

However, it is possible to encode [breadth-first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)/[iterative-deepening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search) search in Prolog using a *meta-interpreter* that changes the search order. This is an extremely powerful technique that is not well known outside of the Prolog world. ['The Art of Prolog'](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/art-prolog) describes this technique in detail.

You can find some examples of meta-interpreters [here](http://kti.ms.mff.cuni.cz/~bartak/prolog/meta_interpret.html), [here](https://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/3_3.html) and [here](http://www.logic.at/prolog/acomip/acomip.html).

Comment: Meta-interpreters what i was searching for! Thanks!

Comment: This research paper also describes the implementation of such an interpreter: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/089396599490104X